# React Typescript: Passing onClick as a Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a simple Hamburger Menu component using React & Typescript.  What I want to do is to pass the `onClick` event handler to this menu componunent as a prop.  This is the code that I currently have:

```
function Hamburger({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <Box
      as="button"
      type="button"
      p="1"
      fontSize="2xl"
      color="gray.600"
      onClick={onClick}
      display={{ base: "block", lg: "none" }}
    >
      <HiOutlineMenu />
    </Box>
  )
}
```

However, typescript complains about the `{onClick}` prop that is being passed:

```
Binding element 'onClick' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

I thought that I could fix this by hovering over the `onClick` key in the `Box` component and seeing what type `onClick` takes.  Hovering over that key produces the following message:

[image]

As such, I thought to modify the `{onClick}` prop as follows:

```
function Hamburger({ onClick }: React.MouseEventHandler | undefined) {
```

But that just produces a new error on `{onClick}`:

```
Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'MouseEventHandler<Element> | undefined'.ts(2339)
var onClick: any
```

I am now at a loss of what to do.  As such, I am wondering -- how should I type `{onClick}`?

Thanks.

Comment: `function Hamburger({ onClick }: { onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler })` should work

Comment: Thanks -- that did it.  If you want, you can add that as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct typing for your `Hamburger` functional component is:

```ts
function Hamburger({ onClick }: { onClick? : React.MouseEventHandler }): JSX.Element {
    // actual code
}
```

As number of props grow, inline type declarations may get messy. So, it's a good habit to move them into designated type:

```ts
type Props = {
    onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler
}

function Hamburger({ onClick }: Props) JSX.Element {
    // actual code
}
```

It also has benefits if later you'll have to accept `children` prop in this component. Then you may use `React.FC` helper with `Props` type:

```ts
const Hamburger: React.FC<Props> = ({ onClick, children }) => { // no need to type `children` prop yourself
    // actual code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
type THamburgerProps = {
  onClick: () => void;
}

function Hamburger({ onClick }: THamburgerProps) {
  return (
    <Box
      as="button"
      type="button"
      p="1"
      fontSize="2xl"
      color="gray.600"
      onClick={onClick}
      display={{ base: "block", lg: "none" }}
    >
      <HiOutlineMenu />
    </Box>
  )
}

function App(){
  return <Hamburger onClick={() => console.log("hanburger clicked!")}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use types provided by react. Consider this:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, MouseEventHandler } from 'react';

interface Props {
  onClick?: MouseEventHandler;
}

const Button: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ onClick }) => (
    <Box
      as="button"
      type="button"
      p="1"
      fontSize="2xl"
      color="gray.600"
      onClick={onClick}
      display={{ base: "block", lg: "none" }}
    >
      <HiOutlineMenu />
    </Box>
);
```